# Autosys Scheduling job every 30 minutes and at a particular time

Tags: scheduling, autosys, jil

So here is the problem, i wish to run a job which runs every 30 and than at 20:15PM.

`start_mins:"0,30"`

gets the work done for every 30 min but I am not able get it running at 20:15.
Using `start_times:"20:15"` in addition to `start_mins` gives error -

> The JIL keyword "start_mins" cannot be specified together with JIL
> keyword "start_times"

One probable solution I can think of is adding all times in start_times like  08:00,08:30,09:00,.....20:15. Is there a better way I am missing here.